# Prevent incorrect moving and spam foldering if filetext contain too values

Tags: powershell

I use this long list in text *.txt* file to move files into YEAR folders
https://pastebin.com/raw/aRP94peb

I have this files (examples) in folder that I want to move

```
Caccia a Ottobre Rosso.torrent
Caccia al delitto
caccia al delitto [divx, test 1986]
```

I use this path, folders

```
C:\Path
Test4.txt
script_powershell.ps1
```

I use this script to move files into own *YEAR* folder: I actually test with powershell 5 to move

```
$movies = @()
(get-content C:\Path\Test4.txt) | foreach($_){
$properties = @{
date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
}
write-host $date
write-host $name

$movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}

$torrentFiles = dir $torrentPath

foreach($movie in $movies){
$datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
}
$words = ($movie.name -split '\s') | ?{ $_.Length -gt 1}
$significant = $words.Count
 foreach($torrentFile in $torrentFiles){
 $matchingWords = 0
  foreach($word in $words){
   if($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word){
    $matchingWords += 1
   }
  }
  if($matchingWords -ge $significant){
  Move-Item -path $torrentfile -Destination $datePath
 }
 }
}
```

But this file

```
Caccia al delitto
```

is moved in `1990` folder but, instead, it should not move because is not in the filetext list..
`1990` folder is correcly generated but also many other spam folders is generated due of long list in .txt list

```
Cont
1982
Zeff
Unde
Stal
Sara
Risi
Norm
Mani
Kasd
Hugh
Harl
```

How to prevent this spam mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

I see several flaws with your approach/code.

- to extract the date you'll need a RegEx to exactly match a year (4digits) at least followed by a closing parentheses. Your pastebin file includes some patterns `(Mux by Little-Boy)` or `(Zeffirelli,1990)` which your substring attempt greps erroneously.
- your matching algorythm will fail completely building a high `$significant` value on lines like:
  `1990 - I guerrieri del Bronx (1982) [BDMux 1080p - H265 - Ita Aac Eng DTS] Azione, Fantascienza`
  with content irrelevant for matching counting ***every*** word with a length greater 1, which a file most probaply won't match. I'd exclude content in square brackets and possibly the trailing categories.
- the code is highly inefficient iterating each line from test4.txt, iterating each file from torrentpath and iterating each word from current file names.
- your usage of `if($torrentFile.BaseName -match $word){` should error out because of the square brackets in line contents being interpreted as an incomplete range; use instead:
  `if($torrentFile.BaseName -match [RegEx]::Escape($word)){`

So this streamlined script will only create correct year folders,
strips off any words follwing a `[` or `(` up to the end
and reverses the ForEach counting/enumerating words in torrent

```
## script_powershell.ps1
$torrentPath = 'A:\Path'
$templates   = 'A:\Test4.txt'

$movies = Select-String -Path $templates -Pattern "\((\d{4})\)" | ForEach-Object {
    $datePath = Join-Path $torrentpath $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        datepath = $datePath
        name = ($_.Line -Replace '(\[|\().*$')
    }
    if(!(Test-Path $datePath)) {
        New-Item $datePath -ItemType "directory" | Out-Null
    }
}

$movies = $movies | Sort -unique Name

ForEach($torrentFile in (Get-ChildItem $torrentPath -File)){
    $words = @(($torrentfile.BaseName -Replace '(\[|\().*$' -split '\s|:|,|\.') -ne ''|
               Where-Object{ $_.Length -gt 1})
    $significant = $words.Count
    $datepath = ''
    ForEach($movie in ($movies|Where-Object Name -match $words[0])){
        $matchingWords = 0
        ForEach($word in $words){
            if($movie.Name -match $word){$matchingWords += 1 }
        }
        # "Movie:{0} `$matchingWords:{1},{2}" -f $movie.Name,$matchingWords,$significant
        if($matchingWords -ge $significant){$datepath = $movie.datepath }
    }
    if ($datepath){Move-Item -Path $torrentfile.FullName -Destination $datePath -confirm}
}
```

The script will only move after confirmation,
to remove this test/security feature, the `-Confirm` paramter following the `Move-Item` has to be commented out/removed.

My test environment after running the script:

```
> tree \ /F
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
A:\
│   script_powershell.ps1
│   Test4.txt
└───PAth
    │   Caccia al delitto
    │   caccia al delitto [divx, test 1986]
    ├───1982
    └───1990
            Caccia a Ottobre Rosso.torrent
```

Comment: Hi LotPings. I test your script. On 8418 files only 2882 files was processed. Here you can check yourself that this files are not moved and there are many strings in text files with year https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ePkteVKHvBhaQw-A_DSxRy62eWPVRqR8/view?usp=sharing -  Is there a more strong condition to move better ?